# Find Messenger Hwnd

Tags: c#, hwnd

Does someone knows how can I find the HWND for all the msn messenger currently opened conversations windows?

OR how can i find the HWND for the textbox whih is currently focused?

TY

Comment: by the way...I'm using c# or vb.net for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spy++ tool which comes with Visual Studio to get the class name of any window of any running program. You can then pass that class name to [FindWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the handle of the appropriate window.

I checked the Windows Live Messenger installed on my system, the conversation windows have the class name: "IMWindowClass".

Comment: It has to be done progrematically. can't ask the user to open spy ++

Comment: I meant that you can use Spy++ to figure out what the window class names are to pass to FindWindow().